# Fixie convention to find test methods in subclasses

Tags: .net

By default `Fixie` smartly looks for test methods in classes with `Tests postfix`. It works smoothly and all you tests are executed without cumbersome xUnit-style attributes. But I tend to group my tests into nested classes according to the name of the method under test:

```
public class ConnectorTests
{
  public class Connect
  {
    ... //Connect method tests
  }

  public class Disconnect
  {
    ... //Disconnect method tests
  }
}
```

If tests are grouped this way, Fixie doesn't see test methods with default convention. How should custom convention look like to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing the following convention:

```
    class TestingConvention : Convention
    {
        public TestingConvention()
        {
            Classes
                .Where(x =>
                {
                    if (x.Name.EndsWith("Tests"))
                        return true;

                    if (x.DeclaringType != null && x.DeclaringType.Name.EndsWith("Tests"))
                        return true;

                    return false;
                });
        }
    }
```

It covers both cases when I have test methods directly in xxxTests class (when tested class has one public method like Query/Command handlers) and when test methods are placed in an innner class.